# To do list with Javascript : can't delete item

Tags: javascript, html, dom, removechild

I made the `remove item` button with the js code while doing the `to-do` list project.

removing items which are earlier made in Code editor works well.
`*so in browser preview, I typed and added "new To-do" item to list.*`
but removing "new To-do" item doesn't work. even chrome Devtool shows no error.  new item's tag and className is all correct.

p.s : don't need to worry about 'X' or X icon. I skipped for uploading.

[HTML]

```html
<ul id="listUl">
    <li>Meet George <span class="remove"></span></li>
    <li>Pay Bills <span class="remove"></span></li>
    <li>new To-do <span class="remove"></span></li>
</ul>
```

[JS] - removing part.

```js
var remove = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');

for (var i = 0; i < remove.length; i++) {
    remove[i].onclick = function() {
        var target = document.getElementById('listUl');
        target.removeChild(this.parentElement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because every new item you add does not have any listener on them (`remove[i].onclick = function(){...}`). So when you click on them, nothing happens. You need to add the `onClick` listener to every new items, like you are doing for the initial ones.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your code:

There is only one (delegated) event assigned now to the `<ul>` parent element, it will trigger only, when the click happens on an element with class="remove". In that case it is the `<span>` element which I also made a bit more visible by adding an "X" inside. Right, when the action occurs I have to go up two levels until I reach the parent of the actual element I want to remove: the `<li>` element.

```js
var i=3,UL=document.querySelector('#listUl');
UL.addEventListener('click',function(ev){
  //   ev.target                       - this element was clicked on
  if (ev.target.classList.contains('remove'))
    // ev.target.parentNode            - this must be the <li> element
    // ev.target.parentNode.parentNode - and this is the <ul> element 
    ev.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(ev.target.parentNode);
})
document.querySelector('#addTask').addEventListener('click',
function(){UL.innerHTML+='<li>and task no. '+(++i)+'... <span class="remove">X</span></li>'})
```

```html
<button id="addTask">add another task</button>
<ul id="listUl">
<li>Meet George <span class="remove">X</span></li>
<li>Pay Bills <span class="remove">X</span></li>
<li>new To-do <span class="remove">X</span></li>
</ul>
```

The "add" button demonstrates how newly created`<li>`s also respond to clicks on the "remove"-span.

Answer (score 1):

Add the onClick listener to ul tag.  Check

```
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
            //Your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the JS code only adds delete function to these todos that already exists when the page loads. Newly added todos will not have `onclick` callback function attached if you only execute your js once when the pages loads.

The workaround here is to attach the callback function every time you create a TODO element.

Answer (score 0):

Your newly (dynamically) added `DOM` elements don't have event listeners attached to them, because on page load, you only iterated (looped) only currently available elements, so You may try the following approach (Read About [Event Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)):

```js
document.getElementById('listUl').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'LI') {
     e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
    }
});
```

```html
<ul id="listUl">
  <li>Meet George <span class="remove">X</span></li>
  <li>Pay Bills <span class="remove">X</span></li>
  <li>new To-do <span class="remove">X</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have jquery added to your page, you can do it like

```js
$('#listUl').on('click', 'span.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$('.add').click(function() {
  $("#listUl").append("<li>Whatever Content <span class='remove'>x</span</li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listUl">
  <li>Meet George <span class="remove">x</span></li>
  <li>Pay Bills <span class="remove">x</span></li>
  <li>new To-do <span class="remove">x</span></li>
</ul>
<butoon class="add">Add</butoon>
```

Comment: really appreciate your comment.  although i'm trying to do vanila JS first. i'll try jquery version later. Thank you.

Comment: In that case you can use The-Alpha's answer